# MGO Query nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I
 am having difficulty converting a MongoDB query to mgo bson.  The Mongo record schema is as shown below.  I want to find records that have topics with label "Education" and "Students".

```
db.questions.insert
(
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5cb4048478163fa3c9726fdf"),
        "questionText" : "why?",
        "createdOn" :  new Date(),
        "createdBy": user1,
        "topics" : [
            {
                "label": "Education",
            },
            {
                "label": "Life and Living",
            },
            {
                "label": "Students"
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

Using Robo 3T, the query looks like this:

```
db.questions.find({$and : [
    {"topics": {"label": "Students"}}, 
    {"topics": {"label": "Education"}}
]})
```

I am having trouble modeling this with MGO.  Currently, have tried this:

```
map[$and:[
    map[topics:map[label:students]] 
    map[topics:map[label:life and living]]
]]
```

and this

```
map[topics:map[$and:[
    map[label:students] 
    map[label:life and living]
]]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bson model for the above answer is as follows:

```
query = getAndFilters(
    bson.M{"topics": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"label": "Students"}}},
    bson.M{"topics": bson.M{"$elemMatch": bson.M{"label": "Education"}}})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find some value from nested array then you use $elemMatch method.

```
db.questions.find(
    {$and: 
        [
            {topics: {$elemMatch: {label: 'Students'}}},
            {topics: {$elemMatch: {label: 'Education'}}}
        ]
    }
)
```

Comment: Using your example, I tried

    map[$and:[map[topics:map[$elemMatch:map[label:students]]] map[topics:map[$elemMatch:map[label:life and living]]]]]

But it returned empty.  My query above does work as expected.  I just can't get it mapped into MGO.

Comment: Indeed, it does work in Rob 3T as does my query above.  But I can not get either to work with MGO.  I am sure that there is some way to map this query to bson.M, but I can not figure out how.

Comment: I did solve the bson problem, and posted the details below.  Thanks.